# Using Stokes's theorem

Tags: vector-analysis

Use Stokes's theorem to show for $\mathbf{F} = -y\mathbf{i} +x\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}$ where the surface $S$ is the southern hemisphere of the unit sphere, i.e. $S$ is defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, $z\le0$.

$$\iint_S \nabla\times\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{dS} = -2\pi.$$

So I want to calculate the integral

$$\oint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{dr}$$

But I am having trouble finding what line to integrate over. Any tips?

Comment: Just the boundary of $S$, i.e. the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ on the $xy$-plane. However, pay attention to the orientation, the line integral need to loop over the unit circle clockwisely....

Comment: @achillehui how do we ensure this? I tried $\mathbf{r}(t) = \cos{t}\mathbf{i}+\sin{t}\mathbf{j}$, where $t$ takes the values $0\le t\le 2\pi$.

Comment: To loop over the unit circle clockwisely, just use the parametrization $r(t) = \cos{t}\mathbf{i} \color{red}{-} \sin{t}\mathbf{j}, t \in [0,2\pi)$.